# What does it mean when someone's an Unregistered User?

Tags: support, unregistered-users

I looked at someone's profile and it said Unregistered User. What does that mean?

Comment: [How do unregistered accounts work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262909/995714)

Answer (score 93, accepted):

They haven't registered themselves on the site. They are logged in with a long living cookie tied to a specific PC/webbrowser. They won't be able to login using the same account on other PCs/webbrowsers.

Comment: They can, by carrying around the cookie in a text file. I did that for quite some time before going through the effort of setting up openid.

Comment: In my world, the "effort" of carrying a cookie around in a text file every where I go is substantially greater than the effort required to set up an OpenID. I guess maybe if you don't already have any other presence on the Internet, an OpenID might be difficult to set up...

Comment: So if I come here and register as an SO/SE user and login with e-mail and password, what's that? I nowhere see any OpenID from SO/SE that I could use in other place, but my bio doesn't show "Unregistered".

Comment: @ShegitBrahm Going by your description, you're using [Stack Exchange's own OpenID provider](https://openid.stackexchange.com/). You can use it on other sites by entering the URL https://openid.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @CodyGray This can still be useful if your firewall blocks access to the specific OpenID provider. Another trick is to use e.g. portable firefox or chrome and carry it on a stick to the firewalled PC (unless that's also blocked, of course).

Comment: @Maarten So use a different OpenID provider?

Comment: OpenID support is closing this mid-year.