# Clarification: New user got his own change to his own answer rejected

Tags: support, suggested-edits, user-accounts, duplicate-user

I was running through reviews and I saw a change to

[How to get javascript control from JQuery object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388306/how-to-get-javascript-control-from-jquery-object/15021694#15021694)

I went to the answer and saw that a user with 1 rep modified his own answer

While I wondered what was going on, the change was rejected.

It was not clear to me on the review page that this was the actual owner of the answer himself - but I skipped the review because of the strangeness of the situation.

Can someone clarify if low rep users are allowed to change their own answer and if not, why not?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1577225 -- the review item.

Comment: Same avatar and detail - different accounts. One is registered, the other is not. Looks like the user is using different devices or has cleared their cookies. If you hover over each avatar, you will see that they link to different user pages.

Comment: Also giving edit-comments in Turkish. o.O

Comment: Wow, I googled translate Kod düzenlendi and google did :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Ünver Kızılay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2098956/unver-kizilay) !== [Ünver Kızılay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2098970/unver-kizilay)

Otherwise, no matter the rep, editing your own post doesn't have to go through the review queue.

Comment: unregistered what that mean ?

Comment: @NullPointer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68524/unregistered-user