# Finding Mathematics Stack Exchange account?

Tags: discussion, support

I started to use the mathematics stack exchange I think in 2015. I was not a regular user but I had been posting questions and, sometimes, gave some answers. And now I try to sign in but find that I have to make a new account.

Why? Has something happend?

Comment: Do you have (or can you find) a link to one of those old questions/answers that you posted?

Comment: @JasonC I have the links to all my questions/answers what I do next?

Comment: Post one of them here. That's why I asked. As for what to do next, see my answer.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1577606/transformation-matrix-and-kernel/1577689#1577689

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either you were an [unregistered user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68524/what-does-it-mean-when-someones-an-unregistered-user) when you were posting questions in 2015, or you used a different email address / login method on that original account. Given that [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/221353/luis-victoria) is your old account, and that it appears to be a registered account, it sounds like it's the latter case.

If you were unregistered, you may no longer be able to access that old account, since it was tied to browser cookies. If it's just a matter of a different email address, which it appears to be, then you'd have to use that same address to log in to it again.

However, in any case, you can [request that your old "account" be merged into your new account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist), then your old questions/answers/etc. will be tied to your newly created account.

Comment: I used another email address, I used facebook before an now i use gmail. Thanks for the answer

Comment: @LuisVictoria Yup, that's the issue. I'd recommend following the instructions in the post about merging accounts, unless you don't care about your current new account and want to go back to using Facebook.